# Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute width="NaN"

Tags: d3.js

I'm completely new to d3.  Ive have completed quite a few charts and examples from "Interactive Data Visualization for the Web" by Scott Murray and had very few problems. This is my first attempt at using a large data-set that is not contained within my code.

d3.csv("historical_weather.csv", function(error,data) {

```
    dataset = data.map(function(d){ 
        return [ parseInt(+d.cloudCover),parseInt(+ d.maxTemp) ];
    })

    console.log(dataset); 

    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("height",500)
        .attr("width",500);

    d3.select("svg")
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data("dataset")
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("height",50)
        .attr("width", function(d){return d.maxTemp*10;});

});
```

The data loads and is visible in the console as an array, I can see the expected values when digging into the array. However the console shows :

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute width="NaN"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you have a typo. The line that says `.data("dataset")` should instead be `.data(dataset)` with no quotation marks. I.e., you should be submitting the `dataset` variable, not a string containing its' name.

Comment: Thanks yony....something so simple caused so much pain. This syntax stuff is killing me!!

Comment: @Banner Agreed, d3js syntax is very ugly.

Answer (score 0):

```
.attr("width", function(d){return d.maxTemp*10;});
```

I believe `function(d){return d.maxTemp*10;}` is registering as array and not a function with a simple return value. Its Not A Number (NaN)

Haven't you defined `function(d)` twice in your script each with totally different meanings?

Comment: That's incorrect. The function is anonymous and is called for each of the elements in `dataset`. The return value is then used to set `"width"`.